# How can I output logs to a file from the content of a service with systemd

Tags: logging, systemd, systemctl, journald, journalctl

Well, I have a service configured with **systemctl**. This is the config file:

```
[Unit]
Description=The description of the service (:
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/echo 'Starting Service' >> /var/log/node/myapp.log
ExecStart=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin/node ./bin/www
ExecStopPost=/bin/echo 'Stopping Service' >> /var/log/node/myapp.log
Restart=always
#StandardOutput=/var/log/node/myapp.log
#StandardError=/var/log/node/myapp.log
SyslogIdentifier=myapp
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/node-apps/theapp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**What I need?:**

1) The `ExecStartPre` and `ExecStopPost` could write the message `'starting service'` or `'stopping service'` to the file `/var/log/node/myapp.log`. With the above configuration, doesn't work, it only outputs `'Starting Service' >> /var/log/node/myapp.log` and `'Stopping Service' >> /var/log/node/myapp.log` to `journalctl`. (I checked with `journalctl -u myapp`)

2) I need that instead of the all logs of the app, outputs to the `journalctl`, could output to a file. Ex: `/var/log/node/myapp.log`. I mean, if in my app, I have a `console.log()`, this could be there.

With **upstart**, I can do it in this way:

```
script

exec start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/upstart-yourapp.pid --chdir /var/www/yourapp/--chuid user:usergroup --exec /usr/bin/node index.js &gt;&gt; /var/log/yourapp.upstart.log 2&gt;&amp;1

end script

pre-start script
    # Date format same as (new Date()).toISOString() for consistency
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" &gt;&gt; /var/log/yourapp.upstart.log
end script

post-stop script
    rm /var/run/upstart-ghost.pid
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" &gt;&gt; /var/log/yourapp.upstart.log
end script
```

But, it is possible to do it with **systemctl**?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar issue. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33036589/560114), it turns out that you can't redirect output directly within `ExecStartPre`, `ExecStart`, or `ExecStopPost` commands - systemd will interpret the `>` or `>>` as arguments. The solution is to execute your command using `sh -c`.

There's also one other issue I ran into when trying to use the `date` command in my systemd script: `%m` is a special code referring to the machine ID of the current host. So in order to have it output the month you need to escape the percent sign by using two percent signs (`%%`). Putting it all together, the systemd version of the above pre and post-scripts is:

```
# Date format same as (new Date()).toISOString() for consistency
ExecStartPre = /bin/sh -c 'echo "[`date -u +%Y-%%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/yourapp.upstart.log'
ExecStopPost = /bin/sh -c 'rm /var/run/upstart-ghost.pid; echo "[`date -u +%Y-%%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/yourapp.upstart.log'
```